# Error en temporizador hecho con java

Tags: java, hilos, timer

Estaba haciendo un programa en java y en este necesito un temporizador que se pueda ejecutar en multiples ocaciones sin cerrar el programa sin embargo solo logro que se ejecute una vez antes de  que me salte un error, en el codigo utilizo 2 Timer de la clase java.util.Timer y dos Timer Task

```
    if(evt.getSource() == jButton3){
        segundos = parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
        total = segundos * 1000;

        TimerTask task1;
        task1 = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        jLabel4.setText("   " + segundos);
                        if(segundos == 1){
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," El Tiempo termino");
                            jTextArea3.setText(area.substring(10,area.length()));
                        }
                        segundos--;
                    }
                };
        t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1,0, 1000);

        TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        t1.cancel();
                    }
                };
        t2.schedule(task2,total);
    }
}
```

este es el otro error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:397)
    at java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Timer.java:328)
    at clases.Principal1.jButton3ActionPerformed(Principal1.java:340)
    at clases.Principal1.access$200(Principal1.java:21)
    at clases.Principal1$3.actionPerformed(Principal1.java:122)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: tu código no está completo, por favor trata de poner siempre un [mcve]

Comment: es que es ahi donde esta el detalle que necesito optimizar

Comment: y el error? sin mas datos esta dificil

Comment: ya inclui los errores que me salto

Comment: por que usas un timer2 para cancelar la primera tarea? eso no es necesario

Comment: lo uso porque el metodo scheduleAtFixedRate se ejecuta cada cierto tiempo pero hasta donde tengo entendido segun lo que vi en la documentacion oficial no puede definir directamente cuando se tiene que detener por eso opte por usar un segundo timer que use el metodo schedule que se ejecuta una sola vez en un periodo de tiempo indicado no se si me equivoco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el código que se provee tiene problemas de Concurrencia, por ejemplo, el código provisto permite que múltiples Task Manipulen el valor `segundos` no solo de forma insegura (el valor no es atómico, o esta sincronizado, no nada) y puede llegar a ser un valor negativo (y creo que esto no es el resultado deseado) por tanto OP, debe revisar que su código permita un Lock y syncronize bien las lecturas y escrituras.

con respecto al problema Reportado, fue simple reproducirlo con el siguiente código:

```
//variables globales de ejemplo
int segundos;
Timer t1 = new Timer();
Timer t2 = new Timer();
TimerTask task1, task2;

//...
//codigo de UI etc etc.
//...

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    segundos = parseInt("10");
    int total = segundos * 1000;

    task1 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
            txtout.setText("   " + segundos);
            if (segundos == 1) {
                txtout.setText("Termino!");
            }
            segundos--;
            }catch(Exception e){
                  Logger.getLogger(ButtonPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }
        }
    };
    t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 0, 1000);

    task2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            t1.cancel();
        }
    };
    t2.schedule(task2, total);
}
```

problemas detectados:

- no hay verificaicon que task1 o task2 sean null o referencias existentes.
- no verifica si ya hay task existentes ejecutandose y descarta cualquier task que YA este ciendo ejecutado!
- permite al Timer t1 y t2 registrar nuevos Task. esto es un problema. puesto estoy casi seguro esto no es lo que OP desea que pase...

En este caso OP requiere cambiar el codigo para que no se permita la ejecucion de Otro task hasta que el anterior Termine. pero antes de mostrar como solucionar Primero mostrar que es lo que pasa: 
[image: digrama de ejecusion](espero que sea lo suficientemente claro)

por tanto, como se muestra en el diagrama anterior.

- si existen 2 Task, el valor de `segundos` se actualiza mas de 1 ves por ***segundo*** e inclusive se puede volver un valor **negativo**
- si se Registran 2 Task en T2 este genera el Error `IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.` dado a que lo Cancelado es el **`T1`** (Todos los task no solo uno en particular) y dado a que Task2(1) se registra para cuando este se ejecute ya **`T1`** cancelo **TODAS** las tareas y  por tanto `Timer already cancelled`.

cómo solucionarlo:

existen varias formas.

1. verificar si T1 tiene Task que no esten Canceladas (Timer no tiene código para hacer. iscancelled() o algo similar por tanto esta opcion es... complicada)
2. hacer que Task2 no Cancele T1 sino que llame Cancel en Task1 (en lugar de T1 que cancela TODAS las task dentro del timer)
3. agregar un Lock o Variable Sincronizada que nos indique si algún Task este ejecutando y no permita que Otro Task sea registrado.
4. (combinación de 2 y 3 )

aparte de esto verificar que las variables que son editadas de forma concurrente sean manipuladas de forma segura (syncronized o que sean atómicas)

por tanto, aquí un ejemplo de posible solución:

```
//variables globales
AtomicInteger segundos = new AtomicInteger();
Timer t1 = new Timer();
Timer t2 = new Timer();
//...
//codigo de UI
//...
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    segundos.set(parseInt("10"));
    int total = segundos.get() * 1000;

    final TimerTask task1 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //el codigo que modifica el UI DEBE ejecutarse en EDT por tanto se usa 
            //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait 
            try {
                java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                    //implisitamente se llama segundos.toString() que es lo mismo que ""+segundos.get();
                    txtout.setText("   " + segundos);
                    if (segundos.get() == 1) {
                        txtout.setText("Termino!");
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ButtonPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            segundos.addAndGet(-1);
        }
    };
    t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 0, 1000);

    TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //cancele la TAREA en particular no todas las Tareas
            task1.cancel();
        }
    };
    t2.schedule(task2, total);
}
```

Sin embargo aquí hay un problema aun! qué pasa si el usuario del app hace click muchas veces al botón? pues funciona, pero `Segundos` se **reinicia a 10** pero hay más de 1 Task que manipula `Segundos` (dado a que es atómico es seguro de se respeta un orden de cambio de valor o lectura del mismo) ***pero*** no se asegura que los task se detengan en 0 o 1! por ejemplo si hago más de 3 click en el botón después de ejecutar el valor de texto me muestra:

[image: segundo error]

en este caso se genera un nuevo problema con múltiples soluciones de nuevo:

1. en el task1 asegurar que cuando se llega a 1 o a 0 el task deje de cambiar el valor del `segundos`
2. auto cancelar el task1 a llegar a 1 o a 0?
3. agregar un Lock o Variable Sincronizada que nos indique si algún Task este ejecutando y no permita que Otro Task sea registrado.
4. Combinación de 1 y 3

en este caso aplicare el 4. :

```
//variables globales
AtomicInteger segundos = new AtomicInteger();
Timer t1 = new Timer();
Timer t2 = new Timer();
//nueva variable global: 
//nos permite saber cuantas Tareas fueron registradas y llevar un control
//aunque nuestro limite es uno podriamos utilizar un Boolean en lugar de Integer...
AtomicInteger taskregister = new AtomicInteger();
//cuantas tareas concurrentes pueden existir? por ahora solo 1 
final int limiteTareas=1;

//...
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (taskregister.get() < limiteTareas) {
        segundos.set(parseInt("10"));
        int total = segundos.get() * 1000;

        final TimerTask task1 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //el codigo que modifica el UI DEBE ejecutarse en EDT por tanto se usa 
                //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait 
                try {
                    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
                        //implisitamente se llama segundos.toString() que es lo mismo que ""+segundos.get();
                        txtout.setText("   " + segundos);
                        if (segundos.get() == 0) {
                            txtout.setText("termino!");
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ButtonPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                //no reste mas cuando llegue a 0
                if (segundos.get() > 0) {
                    segundos.addAndGet(-1);
                }
            }
        };
        t1.scheduleAtFixedRate(task1, 0, 1000);
        taskregister.addAndGet(1);

        TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task1.cancel();
                taskregister.addAndGet(-1);
            }
        };
        t2.schedule(task2, total);
    }else{
        System.out.println(String.format("Existen %d de %d tareas Regitradas en transcurso", taskregister.get(),limiteTareas));
    }
}
```

referencias:

[The Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

[Atomic Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomicvars.html)

[Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html)

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta tan bien estructurada y explicada, me ayudaste a entender mejor los timertask y los timer, tambien por tomarte el tiempo de hacer incluso un diagrama de flujo